# cannot load external js file in android html app

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm trying to load an external js file located on my web server into my android app(HTML5), but it is not working. When I try the html file on my PC browser it works fine, but inside the android browser it does not work.

```
<script src="http://myserver.com/file.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a permission I have to add to my android configuration !!

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.application.store">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Pets">
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="Pets-Book" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to AndroidManifest.xml

You also have to invoke

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

to make it work

Comment: Please post the first 15 lines of the manifest. You might have an error in it

Comment: I posted it in the main post

Comment: Manifest looks fine. You'll have to post MainActivity.java.

Comment: Also, did you try with a simple HTML file containing e.g.  
  <br/><pre>
    <h1>Hello <a href='http://google.com'>World</a></h1>
</pre>
and verified that it was actually visible and that the link would load an external page?